# Can a function access the instance of a class without using global in python?

Tags: python, class, instance, global

Why can I use the instance of a class in the following function without using globals?

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def MyName(self):
        print "My name is: " + self.name

def testFunc():
    # why can I use the instance here?
    print "in testFunc()"
    instance.MyName()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    instance = TestClass("abc")
    print "in __main__"
    instance.MyName()

    testFunc()
```

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__': is still global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, globals are reachable by name from any scope. Your `test_func()` function can *reference* `instance` by name since it has been bound in global scope, namely in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.

The `global` keyword is useful for when you want to *bind* a global name from a local scope. To do so, you declare `global foo` and then bind it, e.g. `foo = 1`, from within the local scope.

Summarized: When *referencing* a global variable by name `global` is not required. When *binding* a global variable, `global` is required.

Answer (score 2):

There is that rule in Python that you can access global names from a function, without `global` as long as you do not try do assigning to them. That is, they are read-only. The `global` is only needed if you are going to assign to a global name.

The rationale is that assigning to a global name is ambiguous: it may mean to create a local name or to assign to a global one. Depending on whether the global name is already defined is a bad idea, so the ambiguity is actually resolved by the `global` keyword.

But reading a name without assigning before is not so ambiguous: it is either a global name or an error. So there is no harm in assuming the global one.

Note that using a name read-only without global, and then assigning to it, is an error.

```
g = 1

def foo1():
    g = 2 #local name

def foo2():
    global g
    g = 2 #global name

def foo3():
    print(g) #global name

def foo4():
    print(g) #global name
    g = 2 # error!
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
class TestClass():
    def foo():
        pass

def test_func():
    instance.foo()

def main():
    instance = TestClass
    test_func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Gives this error:

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 10, in main
    test_func()
  File "test.py", line 6, in test_func
    instance.foo()
NameError: name 'instance' is not defined
```

Do you see the difference?

Answer (score 1):

`testFunc` first searches in its local space:-

```
print locals() #in testFunc.

output:-{}
```

, then it searches in its global space. Try `print globals` in `testFunc`, it has

```
'instance': <__main__.TestClass instance at 0x7f859aca64d0>.
```

hence `instance` is accessible in `testFunc`.

python follows `LEGB` rules hence it searches like:-
**1:-Locals 2:-Enclosing 3:-Globals 4:-Builtins**